# Checkbox's item text selection

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I've got CheckBox which is the  for  of some DataGrid.
Combobox's itemtemplate is:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbxM" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeList}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeValue}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

What I want to achieve is:

When the user clicks on this ComboBox twice the list is closed and he could be able to select text from SelectedItem.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try handling the [`MouseDoubleClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.mousedoubleclick) event for your ComboBox. Then you can change the [`IsEditable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable.aspx) property of the ComboBox and do everything you want to do with it.